# Excel - How to count rows with a criteria but only once for each ID

Tags: excel

In a database, two things are getting logged which is the client id and a status type id - this is getting logged every time a player in-game (who has a client id) has a change in their "ClassTypeID". How would I count the number of times a certain ClassTypeID appears, but only count this once for every client id?

For example if a player with client id 1 changes classes, then changes back, the logs will look something like this:

> ID -- ClassTypeID
>
> 1 ---- 1
>
> 1 ---- 2
>
> 1 ---- 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use something like this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF($A$2:$A$8=E2,1/COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$8,$B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8,E2)))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly the Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: @findwindow because of the errors that would be produced we need to use the SUM(IF()) array with the check to skip those that would produce an #Div0 error.